# Refcusor as input to stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to pass refcursor as input variable to a stored procedure. Like:

```
PROCEDURE TESTPROCEDURE
(p_in IN SYS_REFCURSOR) 
IS
BEGIN

--Stored Procedure logic--

END;
```

It would be really helpful if get some sort of example. Thanks

Comment: simple examples - http://sql-plsql.blogspot.com/2007/05/oracle-plsql-ref-cursors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, refcursor can be passed as input to a stored procedure. E.g.

```
create or replace TEST_PROCEDURE
(
  rc        in sys_refcursor
)
as
data varchar2(10);
begin

loop
    FETCH rc INTO data;
    exit when rc%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('data =' ||data); 
  end loop;

end TEST_PROCEDURE
```